# ¿Cómo crear una sentencia @if elseif al tener un campo unique?

Tags: php, laravel-6

Tengo un formulario y realice una migración en mi archivo 2020_12_10_193619_create_cursos_table.php

En mi tabla tengo lo siguiente `$table->string('email')->unique();`

¿Cómo hago una sentencia mostrando un cadena de texto indicando que el registro ya fue realizado evitando el registro duplicado y la sentencia es colocada en la vista o el controlador en metodo store?